# Visualization SPmenuField in SPGridView

Tags: sharepoint-2010, spgridview, spfield

I have created `SPGridView` and added one `SPMenuField` as the first column and some `BoundFields`. Then I added `MenuTemplate` to the first column. But there are rectangles with white color border. I want to hide them. How can I do it ?

[image: problem grid view]

Here is the code I use:

```
   SPMenuField colMenu = new SPMenuField();
   colMenu.HeaderText = "Title";
   colMenu.TextFields = "Title";
   colMenu.MenuTemplateId = "TitleListMenu";
   colMenu.NavigateUrlFields = "WebId, ListId, ID";
   colMenu.NavigateUrlFormat = "default.aspx?WebID={0}&ListID={1}&ListItemID={2}";
   colMenu.TokenNameAndValueFields = "Param1=ID";
   colMenu.SortExpression = "Title";

   MenuTemplate typeListMenu = new MenuTemplate();
   typeListMenu.ID = "TitleListMenu";

   // ... //

   Controls.Add(typeListMenu);
   customGridView.Columns.Add(colMenu);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/41336/problem-with-visualization-spmenufield-in-spgridview) is the answer on my question. It is nesseccery to narrow the `.ms-menuimagecell` css class.